# Kendo ui - Spreadsheet - how to disable an entire row (not cell) based on a condition?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, spreadsheet

I have a kendo ui spreadsheet which I would like to display remote data and based on a value disable an entire row to prevent user form editing it rather than a cell. Is there any way todo this?? Similar like inline edit for a kendo grid but in this case I would like to edit only certain rows within the spreadsheet??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a range and then disable the whole range. As presented here:
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/spreadsheet/disabled-cells but with rows rather then columns.